# Bookmarks in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, bookmarks

Is not it possible to add a flex url to bookmarks. If not,Please let me know if any alternatives are there. Thank you.

Comment: Please give us more to go on here..
What is it exactly that you are trying to achieve? Code and explanations would be great.

Comment: Hi @DennisJaamann, I want to let my website user add my site to bookmarks.

Comment: Thats exactly why your question is unclear. Your flex application (swf) is embedded in a .html right? Therefore you can of course have your user bookmark your page. But you probably wonder why the bookmark shortcut does not work?

Comment: Thanks for responding promptly @DennisJaamann. What is the reason we dont get shortcut for bookmark and why cant a user copy text from a flex site?

Comment: To make a long story short, when your flex application has focus it will not dispatch your keyboard events to your browser. Therefore you will need javascript to handle this for you. The ExternalInterface provides you with the hooks to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a concept in Flex called deep linking. 
You can read all about it in the [docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=deep_linking_3.html).

You basically just need one class: the [BrowserManager](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/BrowserManager.html).
This class allows you to:

- control the navigation history of your browser
- set window titles for different states of your application
- set specific URL's in your browser's URL bar for different states of your application
- listen for changes in the browser's URL bar, so the state of the application can be changed accordingly

So you can have URL's like

- http://www.myflexapp.com/#dashboard
- http://www.myflexapp.com/#product/123

which can tell your application to display the right information.

Why is there a pound sign in the URL?
That's because we don't want to reload the entire application when the user changes the URL. So we stay on one page with the same app loaded; the part behind the pound signs is information that is being sent to the Flex app, which can change it's state according to this information.

Comment: Note that the deep linking feature requires some functionalities in the HTML/JS side, that Flash Builder automatically generates when the "Generate HTML wrapper file" is enabled in the Flex Compiler section. The default management is implemented in most standard Flex container, however if you need more control you can use the SWFAddress library (http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/), that gives you hooks to manually control application states based on the url anchor (i.e. the part after the "#") and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at: http://code.google.com/p/bookmarks-framework/