# Flex wrapper title

Tags: apache-flex

I need to change browser title via flex.

How can I change the broser title with flex in execution time?

I'm setting the title like this:

```
<mx:Application (xxx) pageTitle="ConfigApp.getTitle()}" (xxx) >
```

Comment: See my answer of a few hours ago here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532910/bookmarks-in-flex/6533052

Comment: BTW: can anyone tell me what is the appropriate course of action in this kind of situation? Do I post a link like a did? Do I post it as an answer? Do I copy/paste my answer?

Comment: A little explanation (in few words or just point that it's a duplicate question) and a link to your previous answer.

Comment: @RIAStar Just add an answer with a link to your answer in the other question. That way others can see that this question has also been answered. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the BrowserManager class for this. It has a function called [setTitle()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/IBrowserManager.html#setTitle%28%29) which does exactly what you want.

The BrowserManager can also handle a lot more interactions between Flex and the browser. I wrote a more elaborate answer on this topic earlier, which you can find here: [Bookmarks in Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532910/bookmarks-in-flex/6533052)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

import mx.managers.BrowserManager;
import mx.managers.IBrowserManager;
import mx.events.BrowserChangeEvent;

private var bm:IBrowserManager;

bm = BrowserManager.getInstance();
bm.setTitle("... Page title xxx ...");